# nltk extract nounphrase with RegexpParser

Tags: parsing, nltk

I want to extract nounphrases from text and i use python with NLTK.
There is a pattern I found in internet of using RegexpParser as follows:

```
grammar = r"""
        NBAR:
            {<NN.*|JJ>*<NN.*>}  # Nouns and Adjectives, terminated with Nouns
        NP:
            {<NBAR>}
            {<NBAR><IN><NBAR>}  # Above, connected with in/of/etc...
    """
    cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
```

I want to modify the grammar variable to add the case 'Noun of Noun' or 'Noun in Noun' ("cup of coffee" or "water in cup" for example)
My test string is : 'postal code is new method of delivery'
I want to receive list of phrases : ['portal code', 'new method','new method of delivery']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Answer is:

```
def ExtractNP(text):
nounphrases = []
words = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(words)
grammar = r"""
     NP:
        {<JJ*><NN+><IN><NN>}
        {<NN.*|JJ>*<NN.*>}
    """
chunkParser = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
tree = chunkParser.parse(tagged)
for subtree in tree.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.label() == 'NP'):
    myPhrase = ''
    for item in subtree.leaves():
        myPhrase += ' ' + item[0]
    nounphrases.append(myPhrase.strip())
    # print(myPhrase)
nounphrases = list(filter(lambda x: len(x.split()) > 1, nounphrases))
return nounphrases
```

Actually, this is not new but I found that the grammar regressions is chunked orderly as they declared. It is mean that the input sentence ('postal code is new approach of delivery') will be cut the content which match to

```
{<JJ*><NN+><IN><NN>}
```

('new approach of delivery'), and then the rest of it ('postal code is') will be compare and used in next matching with

```
{<NN.*|JJ>*<NN.*>}
```

to return 'postal code'. So that, we cannot get the 'new approach' in the returned result.